# Spring 3.0 - Is there a way to create a dynamic bean id from a class constant?

Tags: spring

I'm not sure this is supported but would like to create bean's with id's based on a class constant.  My plan b was to just inject the beans into a class via setters and get a handle on them via IOC.

Thanks!

Comment: No, it's not possible. Can you explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: Spring is being integrated into a legacy app.. for the time being I'm getting a handle to the IOC via ApplicationContextAware interface.  It would be "convenient" to be able to set a bean id = static String.  It's not a big deal to wire the beans into a wrapper class to allow access without knowing the bean id's.

Comment: So you need something like `getBean(SomeBean.MY_ID)`? You can lookup beans by type as well: `getBean(SomeBean.class)`.

Comment: Right on, yea I'm using the latter, by the class.  I was hoping there was a way to set the id to a constant that way I'm not hard-coding some value that I need on the other end.  Thanks again!